# If I get banned on the PC will I get banned on the Xbox One as well, GTA V

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So I'm thinking about buying GTA 5 on the PC and transferring my Xbox One character. However I hear Rockstar bans people on the PC all the time for no reason and if I get banned on the PC I still want to be able to play the character I've invested hundreds of hours in on the Xbox One. So if I somehow get banned on the PC, will my transferred character be banned on the Xbox One as well?

Comment: You hear wrong. If you haven't done anything wrong they will NOT ban you. If you're playing legitimately you're fine!

Comment: Just play fair and don't use any mod and you'll be fine.

Comment: To directly answer your question, yes it would actually be banned since the character is linked to a Rockstar account and they ban the actual account not a specific character. - Sometimes they are temporary if it were to happen. Perma-bans are for people that glitch out the game/hack whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 5):

As it has been pointed out in the comments, you will not get banned if you play the game legit.
If you've transferred your character to the PC, your stats, achievements and progress will be separated and will not be affected by each other.
However, if you find yourself banned, all accounts linked (via Rockstar Social Club) will be banned too.

Answer (score 4):

You can still appeal a false ban, so IF you get banned, just contact Rockstar Support (They're not as bad as everyone says!), But alot of "False Banned" players either exploited, glitched or modded. So you shouldn't worry if you just play the game how it was intended.